# Why is animation rendering not happening even after setting all properties correctly?

Tags: rendering, output

I put output file format as FFmpeg but it is rendering as png file

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Ramos your file crashed my computer when i attempted to render XD

Comment: why is that? what's the reason?

Comment: rendered normally for me. I did change it from mkv to mpg4 though.

Comment: @Ramos Your "Nurbs Path" objects are really highly detailed. Each has 2256 faces, multiplied with 2500 hairs with 100 children each this makes 564 million faces. Maybe your hardware isn't capable of that? I decimated the meshes to around 10% faces of the original mesh, and still it takes quite some time to render a single frame on my not so new computer.

Comment: @Ramos The last comment was just about why it might crash anybody's computer. For the PNG rendering: did you press F12 or Ctrl+F12 to render? Or if you used the top menu _Render_, did you use _Render Image_ or _Render Animation_?

Comment: I used top menu render and selected render animation

Comment: can u tell me how can i decrease the faces or any other method that makes it less laggy